# Function triggering twice when clicked to close panel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code where when I click on the button a panel opens. And in the same script I have **Update()** function  that, checks if I'm clicking outside the button/panel so it can close all open panels. The problem is, when I click on the button to close the panel the panel quickly close and re-opens.

Here is the code I'm using so far. If there is any question or more information I need to give feel free to ask.

Thank you!!

```
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && panel.activeSelf && !RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint(panel.GetComponent<RectTransform>(),
             Input.mousePosition, Camera.main))
        panel.SetActive(false);
}

public void abrir_painel()
{
    if (panel != null)
        panel.SetActive(!panel.activeSelf);
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this?  Put breakpoints in your code, and check the stack when they are hit.

Comment: When is `abrir_painel()` called? Is it an OnClick function?

Comment: @CharlieMalmqvist I created a new function to call the event.(sorry for the delayed response)

Comment: Check if the script is instantiated multiple times (ie add a `Debug.Log` in `Start()` to see if that's also executed multiple times). Happened to me before.